# Dash | I no longer have Duplicate IDs but still get error

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

New to Dash; so go easy on me.

Error:

```
dash.exceptions.DuplicateIdError: Duplicate component id found in the initial layout: `num2-bool`
```

This is because I had 2 Python objects with `id='num2-bool'`.

I renamed the only Python object with `id='num2-bool'` to `id='num2-bool###'`... with now an error for that.

I've since `git pulled`, and my changes are now gone. Yet still, I get the error.

What do I do? Is there Dash cache I have to clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had called upon the variable with that `id` twice...

```
Row([H6(children='Text')]), Row([self.object]),
Row([H6(children='Text')]), Row([self.object]),
```

Comment: Will accpet answer in 48hrs